# XSLT: extract the last x digit of a sibling node with xpath expression

Tags: java, xml, string, xslt, xpath-2.0

I am trying to extract the last 4 numbers of the "red" sibling with xpath.

The source xml looks like:

```
... 
<node2>
    <key><![CDATA[RED]]></key>
    <value><![CDATA[98472978241908]]></value>

    ... more key value pairs here...  

</node2>
...
```

And when I use the follwing xpath: 
 `/nodelevelX/nodelevelY/node2/key[text()='RED']/following-sibling::value`

I have the full number in output, then I tried to extract the digit with this xpath experssion:

`/nodelevelX/nodelevelY/node2/key[text()='RED']/following-sibling::value/text()[substring(., string-length(.)-4)]`

I still have the full number. The substring function does not seems to work.

my xsl header is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
```

I think there is a small error, but I cannot see where. I followed many discussions on SO and others (w3schools) and tried to follow the advices whithout success.

UPDATE: The context:

I use the following identity which copy all the nodes from my source XML to the destination (xml) 
and I apply specific rules for some node after inside a xsl:template:

```
<!-- This copy the whole source XML in destination  -->
    <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- specific rules for some nodes -->

    <xsl:template match="/nodeDetails">
        <mynewnode>
            <!-- here I take the whole value and it s working -->
            <someVal><xsl:value-of select="/nodeDetails/nodeX/key[text()='ANOTHER_KEY']/following-sibling::value" /></someVal>
            <!-- FIXME substring does not work now -->
            <redVal><xsl:value-of select="/nodeDetails/nodeX/key[text()='RED']/following-sibling::value/text()[substring(.,string-length(.)-4)]" /></redVal>
        </mynewnode>
    </xsl:template>
```

And for the transformation I use the following code from a junit class in Java (JDK 6):

```
@Test
public void transformXml() throws TransformerException {

    TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Source xslt = new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream("contract.xsl"));
    Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);
    Source input = new StreamSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream("source.xml"));
    Writer output = new StringWriter();
    transformer.transform(input, new StreamResult(output));
    System.out.println("output=" + output.toString());

}
```

Comment: Could you show us the portion of the XSLT where you are trying to extract this value?

Comment: I do not know if it is important, but the text in all elements are wrapped in CDATA. (question has been updated)

Comment: It might be interesting to you that the answer you have accepted is incorrect.

Comment: It is correct because it is working for my case and answer properly my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current XPath will evaluate to a nodeset, but what you need is a string. Please try something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="value" 
              select="/nodelevelX/nodelevelY/node2/key[. = 'RED']
                      /following-sibling::value[1]" />
<xsl:value-of select="substring($value, string-length($value) - 3)" />
```

Though to be sure about an answer, I'd need to see the portion of your XSLT where you are trying to output this value.

Comment: This makes the assumption that the next `value` element after the red `key` is the sought `value` element, which I think is a safe assumption to make.

Answer (score 0):

**Use this XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
/nodelevelX/nodelevelY/node2/key[text()='RED']
                    /following-sibling::*[1][self::value]
                            /substring(., string-length() -3)
```

**XSLT 2.0 - based verification:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select=
     "/nodelevelX/nodelevelY/node2/key[text()='RED']
                    /following-sibling::*[1][self::value]
                            /substring(., string-length() -3)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<nodelevelX>
    <nodelevelY>
        <node2>
            <key>GREEN</key>
            <value>0123456789</value>
            <key>RED</key>
            <value>98472978241908</value>
            <key>BLACK</key>
            <value>987654321</value>
        </node2>
    </nodelevelY>
</nodelevelX>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the result of this evaluation is copied to the output:**

```
1908
```